# Prove that $\,C^1 \subset H_1 \subset H_\mu\,$ (Hölder Space)

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, continuity, holder-spaces

I need to prove that continuously differentiable functions on $\,\left[a,b\right]\,$ are a subset of Hölder space of order $1$ and that the Hölder space of order $1$ is a subset of the Hölder space of order $\mu$, $\;0 < \mu < 1,\,$ i.e.  $\,C^1 \subset H_1 \subset H_\mu$.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a book or a theorem that proves this?

Comment: It's the same idea for all of those inclusions: pull a part of the exponent of $|x-y|$ aside.